# Will windows 10 partitions work on ubuntu without data lose

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, filesystem, lts

If I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Windows partitions will it remove my media files?

If it removes them, then how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Have you considered using a different hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you don't have experience with Linux.

I suggest you install Ubuntu in a dual-boot (alongside Windows) instead of replacing Windows. The installer shouldn't delete your files, but things can go wrong for a number of reasons, especially when doing something like installing an OS, so having an external backup of your important files is highly recommended.